# Is my count working, and how can i print the count number in the txt file? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code i have for the counter:

```
import mailbox
import pprint
f=open("results.txt","w")
mbox = mailbox.mbox('c:\documents and settings\student\desktop\mail\mail.mbox')
count = 0
for msg in mbox:
 pprint.pprint(msg._headers, stream=f)

  if "('Delivered-To', 'example@example')" in msg:
   count += 1
f.close()
```

This code produces a txt file that looks like this but with 100+ set of email headers one after another:

```
[('X-GM-THRID', '1484400558228312046'),
('X-Gmail-Labels', 'Sent'),
('MIME-Version', '1.0'),
 ('Received',
'by 10.202.231.132 with HTTP; Mon, 10 Nov 2014 07:51:27 -0800 (PST)'),
('Date', 'Mon, 10 Nov 2014 15:51:27 +0000'),
('Delivered-To', 'example@example.com'),
('Message-ID',
'<CAHDwN6i84XGCDAS1+tF_inF=C1ej2BC1af=hJuUab4BqSZf4Qg@mail.gmail.com>'),
('Subject', ''),
('From', '<example2@example2.com>'),
('Content-Type',
'multipart/alternative; boundary=089e01161dfeb060ca05078322b4')]
[('X-GM-THRID', '1482959797700709980'),
('X-Gmail-Labels', 'Inbox,Unread'),
('Delivered-To', 'example@example.com'),
('Received',
'by 10.202.231.132 with SMTP id e126csp70807oih;\n Sat, 25 Oct 2014 11:11:11 -0700       (PDT)'),
('X-Received',
'by 10.194.94.132 with SMTP id dc4mr13227493wjb.56.1414260671373;\n Sat, 25 Oct 2014     11:11:11 -0700 (PDT)'),
('Return-Path', '<robot@one.com>'),
('Received',
'from crm-mailrelay2.public.one.com (crm-mailrelay2.public.one.com. [195.47.247.171])\n     by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id l5si5515662wix.22.2014.10.25.11.11.10\n for     <example@example.com>\n (version=TLSv1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);\n Sat, 25     Oct 2014 11:11:11 -0700 (PDT)'),
('Received-SPF',
'pass (google.com: domain of robot@one.com designates 195.47.247.171 as permitted     sender) client-ip=195.47.247.171;'),
('Authentication-Results',
'mx.google.com;\n spf=pass (google.com: domain of robot@one.com designates     195.47.247.171 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=robot@one.com;\n dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=NONE)     header.from=one.com'),
('Received',
'from crmjb2.one.com (unknown [195.47.247.191])\n\tby crm-mailrelay2.public.one.com     (Postfix) with ESMTP id 627B37D3\n\tfor <example@example.com>; Sat, 25 Oct 2014 18:11:10     +0000 (UTC)'),
('Received',
'from crmjb2.one.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])\n\tby crmjb2.one.com (Postfix) with ESMTP     id 57E7845974\n\tfor <example@example.com>; Sat, 25 Oct 2014 18:11:10 +0000 (UTC)'),
('From', 'robot@one.com'),
('To', 'example@example.com'),
('Message-ID', '<318220617.806451414260670358.JavaMail.root@crmjb2.one.com>'),
('Subject', 'A new drive was created'),
('MIME-Version', '1.0'),
('Content-Type',
'multipart/related; type="multipart/alternative"; \n\tboundary="----  =_Part_154133_94897872.1414260670358"'),
('Date', 'Sat, 25 Oct 2014 18:11:10 +0000 (UTC)')]
```

However, i want to count how many times the header "('Delivered-To', 'example@example.com')" appears in the text file. I have included a count in my code however im not sure if its right. Also, if it is right, how do i print out the count number at the end of the txt file? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `f.write`?

Comment: @Kevin: they are using `f` to pprint to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be confusing a *tuple* containing strings with a *string*.

When looping over the `mbox` object, you are given [`mboxMessage`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html#mailbox.mboxMessage) instances, which is a subclass of the [`email.message.Message` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message). You probably want to use that interface here:

```
for msg in mbox:
    if msg['Delivered-To'] == 'example@example':
        count += 1
```

Comment: Really helpful thanks :) Last thing, how will i know if the count is working? Its counting but how can i print out the count result after the loop?

Comment: @SteCarter93: just `print count`? You could also add a temporary `print count` *in the loop* to see that actual matches are found.

Comment: Yup thats what i thought, however its saying invalid syntax

Comment: @SteCarter93: Python 3 would require you make that a function, `print(count)`.